# If I ZIP a folder in NTFS, is the ZIP file NTFS?

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, zip

If I zip a folder from an NTFS partition, can it be extracted on a device or OS that can't read the NTFS filesystem?

More generally, do zip files preserve the filesystem of the unzipped folder in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I ZIP a folder in NTFS, is the ZIP file NTFS?

No. The "filesystem" within a Zip archive is…Zip, literally.

> If I zip a folder from an NTFS partition, can it be extracted on a device or OS that can't read the NTFS filesystem?

Yes. Any software that supports the Zip format will be able to extract any Zip archive.

When archiving a file, the various filesystem-level metadata is not retrieved as a single opaque chunk of data; the archiver retrieves individual fields as needed (e.g. it copies the actual contents of the file, then it makes one system call to retrieve the created/modified timestamps, then another to retrieve Hidden/Readonly flags...) and stores them in the way that it wants.

So while the archive may replicate some (or even most) filesystem metadata and attributes from the original, the exact way those attributes get stored within the archive is defined **by the archive format** – not by the original filesystem.

Even when the archive does store some filesystem-specific parameters, in most cases programs could simply skip the fields that they don't know what to do with. For example, if you create a Zip file on Linux, it will<sup>1</sup> store the Linux-specific file permission field, but the file can still be extracted on Windows – the extractor will just ignore that field.

Likewise, if you enable the option in WinRAR (or 7zip) to archive NTFS permissions or other NTFS-specific attributes, it will store each of them as individual fields and they will simply be ignored when extracting to incompatible storage.

> More generally, do zip files preserve the filesystem of the unzipped folder in some way?

The filesystem *itself,* no, they do not preserve that (and the software does not even *have access* to files directly at such a low level).

At most, archives preserve some *traits* of the filesystem (and/or the operating system), such as the 'DOS attributes' (Hidden/Readonly/System) that are specific to NTFS & FAT on Windows, or the 'file version' that is specific to ODS on VMS, but those are usually stored in a fairly generic way.

> So if I use a gallery app to add tags to my image files, zip won't necessarily preserve those tags?

Most gallery apps **do not use** filesystem-level metadata for tagging. (In fact, I've only *ever* seen one such app – the built-in tagging that Windows 2000/XP 'Properties' dialogs used to have.<sup>3</sup>) Instead, you usually have the tags either embedded directly within each file's content or stored in an adjacent file.

When you're working with JPEG photos, for example, the EXIF/IPTC/XMP tags are actually part of the file's *data* as far as the filesystem is concerned. Data *is* retrieved as one large chunk of bytes, so EXIF tags embedded in a .jpeg will always be archived together with the rest of the file's data, regardless of the software's metadata-archiving capabilities.

(Probably the only filesystem-level metadata field that gallery apps use might be the "Last Modified" time, in case it differs from the EXIF date. Most archiving apps *do* capture the "Last Modified" time, as it's pretty much universally supported across systems.)

Similarly, e.g. MP3 files have their ID3 tags stored inside the file as regular data; the filesystem remains unaware of them.

---

<sup>1</sup> (Yes, really. See `zipinfo -v`.)

<sup>2</sup> (Zip format also supports custom subfields – Unicode filename is a subfield – so it could in theory be extended to store NTFS metadata as well, if a developer wanted to, but so far nobody has bothered to do so.)

<sup>3</sup> (Windows Longhorn had much grander plans for filesystem-level tagging, but that never happened; instead the feature was removed outright from Explorer in Vista.)

Comment: So if I use a gallery app to add tags to my image files, zip won't necessarily preserve those tags? I should use xml files? Also, is there any metadata that is preserved by some zip software but not others?

Comment: It depends on how those tags were stored – I don't think I've seen any gallery apps use NTFS filesystem-level features to store tags in the first place... Most gallery apps use either a fully separate database file (like sqlite), or they embed tags directly into the EXIF/IPTC/XMP metadata of the photo itself. EXIF is **not** filesystem-level metadata – it is literally part of the file's contents as far as the filesystem is concerned – so it will be archived together with the rest of the file.

Comment: Though if you write your own gallery app that uses NTFS EA or ADS, those will indeed not be archived by tools that don't know how to archive NTFS EA... Yes, different programs have different capabilities when it comes to non-mandatory fields (especially when it comes to Zip which is wildly inconsistent; even Unicode filenames are not 100% supported), and different archive formats also have different capabilities. For example, WinRAR will store NTFS ADS (but not NTFS EA) in .rar archives – but not in .zip archives.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, no.

The Zip format does not store file permissions other than file attributes (read only, hidden, archived and system)

If you create an archive in one folder with certian security permissions, move the file to another folder with different permissions and then extact the archive, the new files will be created with inherited permissions from where the files are stored.

If you want to create a filesystem that you can transfer, use something like a VHDX, where you have a whole partition scheme inside the file. Do note that if you go the NTFS route, that filesystem will only work on your computer, or if the computer is domain joined, and you use a domain user, any computer that is domain joined to the same domain.

You can create a VHDX file using Disk Management. You can even zip the .VHDX afterwards to compress it if you want.

Comment: So zip files can be extracted on any device or OS that supports zip, no matter where they came from?

Comment: Yes, that's what a zip file was designed for. Keep in mind, that even if a zipfile is created on windows or a mac, the other operating system can extract the content, but might not necessarily be able to do anything with it. Some OS'ses will for example allow characters in names that are illegal on some OSses. The zip usually extracts them fine, but might become a problem to even delete the file afterwards.